# Geometric solutions for some particular sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

Some geometric transformations  produce geometric sequences. this question is about that(questions/3765194/geometric-sequences). Here I study the sequences resulting from a particular transformation. The rule is to extend the sides of a polygon, connecting the ends and consider the ratio $R$ of resulting polygon $S_{i+1}$ on the area of original one$S_i$. In this type of transformation the center of gravity remains constant.

[image]

In this figure the transformation of a triangle is shown. We can easily see that $R=\frac{S_{i+1}}{S_i}=7$. Continuing transformation gives following sequence when the area of original one is the first term of sequence:

$R_3: 1, 7, 7^2, 7^3, \cdot\cdot\cdot$

[image]

This fihure show the transformation for a rectangle , where $R=4$ and resulting sequence is:

$R_4: 1, 5, 5^2, 5^3\cdot \cdot\cdot $

[image]

This figure shows transformation for a regular pentagon. The area of a pentagon is:

$A=\frac 14\sqrt{5(5+2\sqrt 5}\cdot a^2$

Where a is the measure of the side. I could not find a relation like when n=3 or n=4. $R_5\approx 3.75$.

For hexagon we can find:

$R_6:  3^2, 3^3, 3^4, 3^5, \cdot\cdot\cdot$

For $n=7$ like for $n=5$ I could not find a sequence such that it's members are a power of an integer. So if n is a multiple of 4 and 6 we may find a sequence of powered integers. I doubt we can find such sequences with number theoretic or algebraic methods when n is prime, although we can always find the terms of such sequences by geometric method.May be trigonometric relation can be found in terms of n but not power of integers. Probably we may use geometric method to find the theory of some unsolved sequences by comparison.

Any idea?

Comment: If you order the points on the initial polygon, can you preserve a corresponding order for successive steps? Then make a ratio of areas that use the shoelace formula?